# A normal divided by $\sqrt{\chi^2(s)/s}$

Tags: normal-distribution, t-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

If $Z \sim N(0,1)$ and $X \sim \chi^2(s)$.  If $Z$ and $X$ are independently distributed then the variable $Y = \frac{Z}{\sqrt{X/s}}$ follows a $t$ distribution with degrees of freedom $s$.

What happens if $Z \sim N(a,b)$?

Does it simply become a location scale t distribution with mean = a,  s.d. = $\sqrt{b}$ still with s degrees of freedom?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not quite.

If $Z \sim \mathcal N(a, b)$,
then note that $Z' = \frac{Z - a}{\sqrt b} \sim \mathcal N(0, 1)$.
Then $Y = \frac{Z'}{\sqrt{X / s}} \sim \mathcal T(s)$.

Now, your proposed location-scale t distribution is $\sqrt b Y + a$. But that is
$$\sqrt b Y + a = \frac{\sqrt b Z'}{\sqrt{X / s}} + a = \frac{\sqrt b Z' + a \sqrt{X / s}}{\sqrt{X / s}} \ne \frac{\sqrt b Z' + a}{\sqrt{X / s}} = \frac{Z}{\sqrt{X / s}}.$$

The variable that you care about is instead a scaled [noncentral t-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_t-distribution), with $s$ degrees of freedom, noncentrality parameter $a / \sqrt b$, and then scaled by $\sqrt b$:
$$
\frac{Z}{\sqrt{X / s}}
= \frac{\sqrt b Z' + a}{\sqrt{X / s}}
= \sqrt{b} \left( \frac{Z' + a/\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{X / s}} \right)
.$$

Comment: Apologies if I'm misunderstanding, but your stated location-scale t distribution is $\sqrt b Y + \frac{a}{\sqrt b}$. But that is
$$\sqrt b Y + \frac{a}{\sqrt b} = \frac{\sqrt b Z'}{\sqrt{X / s}} + \frac{a}{\sqrt b} = \frac{\sqrt b Z' + \frac{a}{\sqrt b} \sqrt{X / s}}{\sqrt{X / s}} \ne \frac{\sqrt b Z' + a}{\sqrt{X / s}} = \frac{Z}{\sqrt{X / s}}.$$ Im sure I am making an error, any help would be massively appreciated

Comment: @CharlesPrice That's my point: $\frac{Z}{\sqrt{X / s}}$ is _not_ a location-scale t distribution at all, but a noncentral t distribution, which is not the same thing. I just edited a bit to try to make that clearer.